# Is there a Technique or Algorithm for Building Spheres?

Tags: building, shapes

There are times when I would like to build a sphere or a dome like this one:

[image]

From [Small Lego Sphere Project](http://www.brillig.com/lego/sphere/)

While this example is great, I find it difficult to scale it to another size, whether smaller or larger, without it...not looking roundish anymore.

Is there a tool available that can design a sphere or dome based on a size?

Comment: this questions reminds me of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10910/88 ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This website generates a sphere in LDraw format: http://lego.bldesign.org/sphere/

Here's a link if you want to learn how it can be done: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F04/assignments/assignment5/
(there are other ways too)

Answer (score 11):

Here is my less popular but earlier Spheroid Generator

http://olson.pair.com/moc/spheroid/

It let's you generate simple sphereres or ellipsoids as well as parabolic "tent" shapes.

The principle is to divide space into 1x1 brick or plate cells, and any cell that falls mostly within an ideal geometric shape becomes a brick (or plate).

Output is LDRAW model format using 1x1 bricks and divided into step numbers.

Alternate approaches divide the sphere into facets for SNOT building; my program can't do that.

I could be persuaded to pick up the project again after 10 years...

Answer (score 4):

I have done it see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxo4BrypNZ0) video.

I have updated the spreadsheet so that it can give you a visual indication of the cross-section at each layer (in quarters) and uploaded it onto [Google drive for public access](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4lSGXXuLbczRkZ3clNOVHJsQnM/view?usp=sharing)