# Is there a good way to build a dome on the top of a building?

Tags: building

How can I build a dome on top of a building, similar to a [state capital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Capitol) or something similar?

The building has a base of 16x24 studs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a dome is typically a hemisphere, [this topic about building spheres](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/549/is-there-a-technique-or-algorithm-for-building-spheres) might be very useful for you. There's also an [automatic tool to construct spheres](http://lego.bldesign.org/sphere/) that you could use to get an [ldraw](http://www.ldraw.org/)-plan.

Answer (score 9):

Like oezi said you can build a dome out of cascading bricks, which is perfect for most scales of building. For smaller scale building where you'd want a less jagged approach you may want to use a combination of [1/4 dome pieces](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=88293). A complete dome will take up an area of 6x6 studs wide.

This technique is common in the [Prince of Persia](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Prince%20of%20Persia) sets.

[image: The Fight for the Dagger]

---

For a true miniland scale building you may want to have a closer look at the model in Legoland Florida.

[image]